# Check if a column has any extended properties

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find out if a column has any extended properties. I need a query to pull all database properties and extended valued. So far I have written this:

[image]

I need to find if a column from `tb2` has any extended properties and if it has to print it out with the rest of information.

Comment: You should post the code as **property formatted code** - not as a screenshot thereof.....

Comment: People will be much quicker to help you if you code is text so they can copy and paste it out to modify it. No one wants to type it all in again. Also please some expected results and actual results also as **formatted text** not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is what you need:

```
DECLARE @ExtendedPropertyColumnList nvarchar(max)
= 
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(ep.EPName), ',')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ep.[name] AS EPName 
        FROM sys.extended_properties AS ep
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
        ON c.object_id = ep.major_id
        AND c.column_id = ep.minor_id 
        INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
        ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
        ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id 
        INNER JOIN sys.types AS typ
        ON typ.system_type_id = c.system_type_id 
        AND typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id 
        WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND t.[name] <> N'sysdiagrams'
    ) AS ep);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'
WITH ColumnsToList
AS
(
    SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
           t.[name] AS TableName,
           c.[name] AS ColumnName,
           c.is_nullable AS IsNullable,
           typ.[name] AS DataTypeName,
           c.max_length AS MaximumLength,
           c.[precision] AS [Precision],
           c.scale AS Scale,
           ep.[name] AS ExtendedPropertyName,
           CAST(ep.[value] AS nvarchar(max)) AS ExtendedPropertyValue
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS typ
    ON typ.system_type_id = c.system_type_id 
    AND typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS ep
    ON ep.major_id = c.object_id 
    AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id 
    WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND t.[name] <> N''sysdiagrams''
)
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM ColumnsToList 
) AS ctl
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(ExtendedPropertyValue)
    FOR ExtendedPropertyName IN (' + @ExtendedPropertyColumnList + N')
) AS epp;';

EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

I've updated again to make it dynamically work out the columns.

Comment: Almost . This is great but I need this combined with the result from infromation_schema.columns. What I need is all the properties and extended properties of a database. Thank you in advance

Comment: You shouldn't really use the old information schema views any more. sys.columns has everything useful about a column. Please show us an example of what you need out.

Comment: I've expanded it with a few more properties so you can see what to do.

Comment: Hey guys, based on Greg's script how can I add to the rezult a column with extended value for each extended property(let's say that a column has multiple extended property, I need the result to be like: table name, column name, value for extended property1, value for extended property2 and so on). Sorry for all the questions but I am new to this(just finished an online course about laravel) and this is my first task as junior. Thank you in advance

Comment: I've updated it to put all the extended properties for a column in the same output column.

Comment: That is great greg but each extended value should be in separate column. Basically you will have a column for each extended property value. Many thanks

Comment: OK, I've added the dynamic code required to make it work with separate columns.